# Drag and drop not working for on the fly elements firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

I have a page that generates some draggable elements.
However I noticed that on firefox I cannot get them to drag while on chrome I can.To create a new element i press the create  item button.Here is my code

```js
/*
* @param event A jquery event that occurs when an object is being dragged
*/
function dragStartHandler(event){
 //e refers to a jQuery object
 //that does not have dataTransfer property
 //so we have to refer to the original javascript event
 var originalEvent = event.originalEvent;
 var currentElement = originalEvent.target;
 console.log("Hack it");
 console.log($(currentElement).data());
 //We want to store the data-task-id of the object that is being dragged
 originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text",$(currentElement).data("task-id"));
 originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 //When a new task/item is creatted it is assigned a unique data attribute which is the task index
 var taskIndex = 0;
 $(".text-info").addClass("text-center");
 $(".createTask").addClass("btn-block").on("click",function(){
  //Find the category whict this button belongs to 
  var currentCategory = $(this).parent(".box");
  var categoryId = currentCategory.data("category");
  //Create a new task
  var task = $("<div class='list-group-item droppable' draggable='true' data-task-id="+taskIndex+"></div>");
  //Assign a data-task-id attribute and set its text
  task.text("Data id = "+taskIndex);

  taskIndex++;
  task.appendTo($(this).prev(".dropTarget"));
 });
 $(".droppable").on("dragstart",dragStartHandler);
 $(".dropTarget").on("dragenter",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass("highlighted-box");
 }).on("dragover",false)
 .on("drop",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var originalEvent = event.originalEvent;
  //Retrieve the data-task-id we stored in the event
  var taskId = originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  console.log(taskId);
  //The object that will be moved is determined by the id we stored on the event parameter
  var objectToMove =$("body").find(`[data-task-id='${taskId}']`);
  console.log(objectToMove);
  var category = $(this).parent(".box").data("category");
  objectToMove.data("category-group",category);
  //Remove the square object from its previous position 
  //and append it to the current dropTarget
  $(objectToMove).appendTo(this);
  return false;
 });
});
```

```css
.highlighted-box {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 4px #EBE311;
}

.dropTarget {
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    /* border:2px solid; */
    margin: auto;
}
.dropTarget .droppable{
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 top: 20%;
}
.droppable {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
   /*  height: 6em;
   border-radius: 5px; */
   /*  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #3D0404; */
    /* width: 6em; */
}
#square2{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="jumbotron intro text-center">
  <h1>Drag and drop demo</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 box" data-category="0">
   <h1 class="text-info">Ideas</h1>
   <div class="dropTarget list-group">
   </div>
   <div class="btn btn-info createTask">
    Create item
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 box" data-category="1">
   <h1 class="text-info">Wornking on</h1>
   <div class="dropTarget list-group">
   </div>
   <div class="btn btn-info createTask">
    Create item
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 box" data-category="2">
   <h1 class="text-info">Completed</h1>
   <div class="dropTarget list-group">
   </div>
   <div class="btn btn-info createTask">
    Create item
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 box" data-category="3">
   <h1 class="text-info">Accepted</h1>
   <div class="dropTarget list-group">
   </div>
   <div class="btn btn-info createTask">
    Create item
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="square" draggable="true" data-index = "0" class="droppable list-group-item"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="square2" class="droppable list-group-item" draggable="true" data-index="1"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Attach the drag*/drop events on the new elements, or use delegated event handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code was the event delegation.
To fix it I did the following:

```
$("body").on("dragstart",".droppable",dragStartHandler);
```

Here you can find more more [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)